# html pass parameters to frame using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help with passing parameters from URL to frame.

Example : my url - `http://mysite.com?var1=2&var2=3`

I got two frames that should open those links-

1. frame1  - `http://othersite.com?id=<value of var1>`
2. frame2  - `http://othersite.com?id=<value of var2>`

I need to build a web page that opens two url in two frames.
in order to do that i would like to pass parameter to the two iframe i have:

using this url to open it : http://mysite.com?var1=242

the page contain this code:

```
     <frame name="frame1" src="http://myapp?id=<value of var1>#tab1">

     <frame name="frame2" src="http://myapp?id=<value of var1>#tab2">
```

how to do that ? put the value of 242 in the src of each frame ?

New to JS.

Thanks,

Paka.

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i added more information hope it help. it a simple thing that i don't know how to do. open new pages with two frames that read parameter from the url and use it inside the src .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just leave the `src` of the `frame`s empty/out in the HTML, then add a script to the `head` section of the `frameset` page:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var n, key, vars = {},
        searchString = window.location.search;
    searchString = searchString.replace(/^\?/, '').split('&');
    for (n = 0; n < searchString.length; n++) {
        key = searchString[n].split('=');
        vars[key[0]] = key[1];
    }
    window.frames['frame1'].frameElement.src = 'http://myapp?id=' + vars.var1 + '#tab1';
    window.frames['frame2'].frameElement.src = 'http://myapp?id=' + vars.var2 + '#tab2';
}
```

Also a search string is supposed to be the last part of the url. If your `id`s are not like `242#tab1`, you need to do it this way:

```
window.frames['frame1'].frameElement.src = 'http://myapp#tab1?id=' + vars.var1;
```

If setting the `src` of the `frameElement` doesn't work for you, you can set the location of the `window` in the `frame`:

```
window.frames['frame1'].location.href = 'http://myapp#tab1?id=' + vars.var1;
```

Comment: You query string parsing is invalid.

Comment: How is that? The original url calling the `frameset` page is `http://mysite.com?var1=242` --> `var1 === '242'`. Thoug it's not a general query, it anwsers OP's question.

Comment: The url is `http://mysite.com?var1=2&var2=3` and so you'd be capturing `2&var2`.

Comment: Hmm... I read this: "`using this url to open it : http://mysite.com?var1=242`".

Comment: I suppose he's being inconsistent, but he gave as an example the 2-parameter URL. Of course it's best practice to parse it in full, but you could just add a `.split('&')[0]` and it'd be more robust.

Comment: Hi , Thanks. testing it on local files works fine but trying to load the page from my web server didn't work. the url's on each frames get empty and didn't get any vars from the java script. any idea why ? BTW i asked for two params but it can be with 1 for start.

Comment: @matt3141 I have added a general search string handling to my answer.

Comment: @Paka There was an error in the previous code. I've fixed my answer.

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript parse the query string and then set the `src` of each frame, for example:

```
<script>
    var params = (function() {
        var obj = {};
        location.search.substr(1).split('&').forEach(function(eq) {
            var pair = eq.split('=');
            obj[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        });
        return obj;
    }());
    [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('frame'), function(frame,index) {
        frame.src = ['http://myapp?id=', params["var1"], '#tab1'].join('');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where this snippet should be placed? When it should be executed? `forEach()` is not a cross-browser method, some browsers include `?` to the `location.search`, and the same `src` is attached to every `frame` on the page...